# Bibliography references by hand

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

For my Master's thesis, I used a formatted latex bundle so I would not have to worry about my University's many formatting requirements. However, the downside is that the Bibtex does not work. I tried to fix it when I started working on it with no luck. Now that I am almost done, since I'm running out of time, I am just going to implement my references by hand.

Problem is, imagine once I am done, I have to add one reference at the beginning of my thesis, I do not want to go over every single reference and add a number to it (reference 10 would become 11, 11 would become 12 and so on....). Is there an easy way to automate this?

Comment: If you have a bib file and if you used already cite commands I would at first try to find out "why bibtex doesn't work". It could save you a lot of time. Is the latex bundle available somewhere so that someone could test if it is faulty?

Comment: on the long run it would save me time, but since I am very short on time right now (deadline in a few hours), I'd rather get started now that try solving problem that could take a couple hours for all i know!

Comment: Well I don't know how much references you have and so don't know if the few hours will be enough to enter all of them manually. If you think you can manage it and if you used \cite in your document you should use the the bibliography environment as suggested by samcarter. If the bib contains only the references you cited you could also try to create the environment in an external document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like

```
\begin{thebibliography}{plain}
    \bibitem{autor2009}
        \textit {Autor, F. {\it et al.} (2009).}
        \newblock Title\\
\end{thebibliography}
```

work for you?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks to you and @UlrikeFischer that told me how to cite the reference.

Comment: @user123456, it probably should, but you could try `\begin{thebibliography}{unsrt}`

Comment: The second argument of the `thebibliography` environment should generally be a number, e.g., `9`, or `99`. Arguments such as `plain` (or `unsrt`) are borderline misleading since they suggest that a specific BibTeX bibliographyle is being used -- which clearly isn't the case if you're building the bibliography "by hand".